# Regex for capital letters not matching accented characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I am new to ruby and I'm trying to work with regex.

I have a text which looks something like:

```
HEADING

Some text which is always non capitalized. Headings are always capitalized,     followed by a space or nothing more.

YOU CAN HAVE MULTIPLE WORDS IN HEADING
```

I'm using this regular expression to choose all headings:

```
^[A-Z]{2,}\s?([A-Z]{2,}\s?)*$
```

However, it matches all headings which does not contain chars as Č, Š, Ž(slovenian characters).

So I'm guessing [A-Z] only matches ASCII characters? How could I get utf8?

Comment: What's your expected output? did you want to match also the letters other than `[A-Z]` ?

Comment: I want to match:

HEADING
and also:
HEADING ČŽŠ, but I thought those letters are already matched in [A-Z], but doesnt look like it..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are right in that when you define the ASCII range `A-Z`, the match is made literally only for those characters. This is to do with the history of characters on computers, more and more characters have been added over time, and they are not always structured in an encoding in ways that are easy to use.

You *could* make a larger character class that matches the slovenian characters you need, by listing them.

But there is a shortcut. Someone else has already added necessary data to the Unicode data so that you can write shorter matches for "all uppercase characters":  `/[[:upper:]]/`. See http://ruby-doc.org//core-2.1.4/Regexp.html for more.

Altering your regular expression with just this adjustment:

```
^[[:upper:]]{2,}\s?([[:upper:]]{2,}\s?)*$
```

You may need to adjust it further, for instance it would not match the heading "I AM A HEADING" due to the match insisting each word is at least two letters long.

Without seeing all your examples, I would probably simplify the group matching and just allow spaces anywhere:

```
^[[:upper:]\s]+$
```

Comment: How would I use string split so that it splits, lets say recipes, from text.. such as:
RECIPE ONE
use this and this and this
RECIPE TWO
this and other

I would like to split text by heading into recipes..

Comment: @NejcLovrencic: That seems like a new question to me, please don't extend your question with next parts of your project. Maybe you could look at Ruby's `String#split` and `String#scan` methods as possible starting points.

Answer (score 3):

You can use unicode upper case letter:

```
\p{Lu}
```

Your regex:

```
\b\p{Lu}{2,}(?:\s*\p{Lu}{2,})\b
```

[RegEx Demo](http://rubular.com/r/8m6s4uMB5g)